# Bind and connect simultaneously on 2 network interfaces

Tags: java, sockets, connect

i'm trying to create a HTTP Proxy that can download simultaneously via many network interface in Java , But the problem is that on Windows => after using de bind() fonction of the socket, the socket is always using one interface connection. so after receiving a GET request i'm creating / binding the socket on different interface by using my ip address in the specified network by :

```
sock = new Socket();
sock.bind(new InetSocketAddress(Ip_Interface, 0));
sock.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, (int) pt));
```

where Ip_Interface is my ip address in one of my interfaces
'host' and 'port' represents the remote server on wich i want to connect.

On Ubuntu 14.04, when i'm trying to do the same thing, the server doesn't respond and i am always a ConnectException: Connection timed out. So i'm so confused

Why does the bind() function of the socket doesn't work?
How can i achieve this functionnality ?

Comment: The simple answer is not to use `bind()` at all for client sockets. There is rarely any need for it, and if this case is an exception you haven't stated why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### It will not just magically happen via software.

If you want to bond multiple interfaces together to increase bandwidth for throughput you can only do this in hardware and all the hardware in the chain has to support what is called [Link Aggregation (LACP)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_aggregation). This means the only benefit you could get would be on your internal network between machines that support LAPC and they all have to be connected via switches that support LACP.

If you want to transfer via multiple interfaces you will have to manage multiple sockets yourself, this is a non-trivial problem to solve and way out of scope for Stack Overflow.